# surface area of a parametric curve or revolution

Tags: parametric, surface-integrals

I have the equations $x=9t-3t^3 $ and $ y=9t^2$ , $0\le t\le 2$ rotated about the x-axis

what I did to try and solve this was:

$ S= \int^2_0 2\pi(9t^2) \sqrt{(9-9t^2)^2+(18t)^2}dt $

$S= \int^2_0 18\pi t^2 \sqrt{81t^4 +162t^2+81}dt $

$ S=\int^2_0 18\pi t^2 (9-9t^2)dt $

$S= \int^2_0 162\pi t^2 (t^2+1) dt $

$ S= 162\pi [\frac{t^5}{5} +\frac{t^3}{3}] $

$ S= \frac{7344\pi}{5}$

I'm not sure where I went wrong , any help pointing that out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hence you are claiming you went wrong somewhere I guess you know the right solution. Could you please add the right one somewhere? I think it is easier to seach for a mistake by knowing what the outcome should look like.

Comment: Furthermore I have to say that I cannot spot any mistake beside the typo with the third line where it should be $(9+9t^2)$.

Comment: Do you understand "How this curve is"?　Your calculation is correct when x increase monotonically.

Comment: wolfram alpha show this curve need a few integrals. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D9t-3t%5E3,y%3D9t%5E2,+0%3Ct%3C2